# How do I display an exception's full stacktrace in Google App Engine's app log?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, exception

While detaching an object from the datastore in a deployed app on Google App Engine, I'm getting an "failed to detach" exception that I can't reproduce on my development box. The detach operation is server-side, so the only information I have on it is the log of the exception in the app's log files. However, the stacktrace is elided: for example, the deepest internal exception ends with "... 36 more".

How do I adjust the verbosity of the app's logging to include the full, non-elided stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things that you can possibly tweak:

1) In `war\WEB-INF\logging.properties` file. Change the .level value to a level lower e.g. DEBUG.

2) In your Java code, look at encapsulating the problem code within a `try/catch` so that you have control of the same.

3) In the `catch` block, look at logging the exception data via `ex.printStackTrace()`, where ex is the exception object.

Comment: @cqcallaw - changed to what? There's no DEBUG level in Java's default logging: java.util.logging.Level.

Comment: In the logging.properties file, you will find a line like ".level = WARNING". Just change that to ".level = DEBUG" and try.

Answer (score 7):

What you can do is to add the Throwable as a parameter when logging an exception. ie:

```
 Logger log = Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class.getName());
 .....
 }catch (final Throwable e){
       log.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
 }
```

This will print a nice stack trace on GAE's logs.

This way you don't have to change the global log level.